# IE9 set innerHTML of textarea with html tags

Tags: internet-explorer-9, innerhtml

I have this field

In IE9 the following line gives me the error 'SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error '
//option 1.
document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = 'some text';

The error disappears and it seems to work (assiging empty value) when I change the line to:
//option 2.
document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = '';

The I tried this:
//option 3.
document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = escape('some text');

but then the HTML gets to be escaped and thats not what I want, I want this exact string to be placed in the textbox.

In Chrome and Firefox the code in option 1 does run correctly.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [`value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535122.aspx).

Comment: wow! +1 for the solution. spent hour to figure out the issue as it was working in firefox and chrome. IE was just throwing unknown runtime error :(

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, does your webpage have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` or similar?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/24/ie9-s-document-modes-and-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 quirks mode accepted solution won't work.

As you are probably trying to set `innerHtml` for `<p>`, it will work if you replace `<p>` with `<div>`.

Credits: Theo Gray, http://www.theogray.com/blog/2009/06/internet-explorer-unknown-runtime-error