# Remove table from <div> tag

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html-table

I have a `<div>` tag in which I add `<table>` dynamically through Javascript:

```
var htmlText = "<table id='table_" + id + "'><tbody>";
htmlText += "<tr> <td><img src='../../Icons/action_delete.gif' onclick='javascript:RemoveUser(\"" + id + "\");' /></td> <td>" +  name + " </td></tr>";
htmlText += "</tbody></table>";
document.getElementById("divSearchUsers").innerHTML += htmlText;
```

I add multiple table to the div. Now I want to remove a particular table.
I get the ID of the table in RemoveUser function. How do I proceed for it?

Comment: Kindly go through the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with relation to non jQuery:

[Remove dom element without knowing its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804991/remove-dom-element-without-knowing-its-parent)

```
function removeElement(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since id of html element is supposed to be unique, you can directly delete it using remove methos.

*With jQuery*

```
$('#tableIdToRemove').remove();
```

*With Javascript*

```
tableIdToRemove = document.getElementById("tableIdToRemove");
tableIdToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(tableIdToRemove);
```

or

If you have html and there is `chance of duplicate ID` out side the parent table then you can access the table to delete in relation to its parent table as follow.

```
$("#divSearchUsers").find('#tableIdToRemove').remove();
```

Comment: For elements with an ID, just use `$('#tableIdToRemove')`.  Under the hood, jQuery is going to use `document.getElementById` which will be faster and simpler than the second example you show.

Answer (score 2):

Get the element id and use remove()

```
$("#table_id").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove the inner html then you should just do something like that:

```
document.getElementById('table_' + id).innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: @user1509 Please check this [`link`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7332175/1577396).. might help you